# How to modify the Timeseries forecasting for weather prediction example to increase the number of predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

(And plot them all in the same figure).

I've been following the "Timeseries forecasting for weather prediction" code found here:
https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_weather_forecasting/

The article says:
"The trained model above is now able to make predictions for 5 sets of values from validation set."

And it uses this code to get predictons and plot them:

```
def show_plot(plot_data, delta, title):
    labels = ["History", "True Future", "Model Prediction"]
    marker = [".-", "rx", "go"]
    time_steps = list(range(-(plot_data[0].shape[0]), 0))
    if delta:
        future = delta
    else:
        future = 0

    plt.title(title)
    for i, val in enumerate(plot_data):
        if i:
            plt.plot(future, plot_data[i], marker[i], markersize=10, label=labels[i])
        else:
            plt.plot(time_steps, plot_data[i].flatten(), marker[i], label=labels[i])
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlim([time_steps[0], (future + 5) * 2])
    plt.xlabel("Time-Step")
    plt.show()
    return


for x, y in dataset_val.take(5):
    show_plot(
        [x[0][:, 1].numpy(), y[0].numpy(), model.predict(x)[0]],
        12,
        "Single Step Prediction",
    )
```

In my computer in order to downsample the series to 1 hour... instead of using "sampling_rate=6" I have directly modified the frequency of the input data and I'm using "sampling_rate=1"

Now, considering that the model was fitted properly... What do I need to modify if I want to get predictions for the next 500 intervals instead of just 5?

`dataset_val.take(500)`

Or something else?

The configuration at the beginning also says:

```
split_fraction = 0.715
train_split = int(split_fraction * int(df.shape[0]))
step = 6
past = 720  
future = 72
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size = 256
epochs = 10
```

What values do I need to use now for past and future (if my data has a frequency of 1 hour and I want to predict 500 points forward?
future = 500
past = ?  (it seems to be the number of timestamps taken backwards for training)

What about delta? It's fixed to 12, but it seems to be the value for future.

Comment: `What do I need to modify if I want to get predictions for the next 500 intervals instead of just 5?` - you misunderstood. This model was trained to predict a single point 72 intervals into the future based on 720 most recent intervals. From the link: `We are tracking data from past 720 timestamps (720/6=120 hours). This data will be used to predict the temperature after 72 timestamps (72/6=12 hours).`. If you want to predict 500 intervals into the future, you need to re-train the model, but you'd only need to change the `future` parameter. And `step` for different frequency.

Comment: To predict 500 points instead of just one, you'd need to feed it 500 different intervals, sliding over your dataset (from now - 500 steps to now). Length of these intervals will be equal to `past`, but each prediction will only give you a single point.

Comment: @Lodinn Yes, I understood that, maybe I didn't explained it well.
But I guess if we want to increase the distance of the future interval we also need to increase the number of past timestamps used to train.

Comment: If my input data is not 10min anymore but 1hour (because I have converted) then I just need step=1. Isn't it?

Comment: What I don't know is, while predicting and plotting... What is  the value I need to write inside the dataset_val.take(). Is it 500?. What does this value mean? It just takes the element in position 500?

Comment: I think there is an error in the original code.
There is a fixed parameter delta=12, which should be changing at every time step.

Comment: ` if we want to increase the distance of the future interval we also need to increase the number of past timestamps used to train.` - well, for the purposes of the model, that doesn't really matter, but sure, it makes sense. Again, this length of the sequence is controlled by the `past` parameter. `for x, y in dataset_val.take(5):` shows 5 plots. `take(500)` would show 500 plots. Indeed, prediction happens in the call to the plotting function, so you would need to rewrite this part. Take just gets you a few sequences from a dataset.

Comment: The dataset itself is built using https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/timeseries_dataset_from_array. It is simply a collection of sequences. A better way of predicting multiple values is what Amin suggests, adjusting the model itself so it outputs more than one prediction for a series. You would likely need a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

according to the source
https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/timeseries/timeseries_weather_forecasting.py
, here is the model

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(inputs.shape[1], inputs.shape[2]))
lstm_out = keras.layers.LSTM(32)(inputs)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(lstm_out)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), loss="mse")
model.summary()
```

as you can see it uses a 1 unit Dense as a last layer. if you want for example 2 predictions u should use 2 units for Dense(as a last layer) and should be careful about the input shape of ( X_train, Y_train) and (X_Validation, Y_Validation) because your expected Y as a default has a 1 unit so probably you should convert it.
Simple example
Default X:1,Y:1 changes to X:1,Y:1,2

and probably Y data should be shifted(N) which N is exactly the number of units in the last layer(Dense).

---

If you just want to predict a bigger time frame you can convert your whole Data to the bigger one.
e.x our default Time frame and data (weather) is per hour. then we can convert our data to the daily ( which is x24 ) and then we can predict daily or the same thing (X30) and we can predict monthly and so that.

Comment: But one I have the model able to predict the points (I think increasing the values of past and future)...
How can I plot the predicted points all in the same figure?
Do I need to modify those "12" and take(5) values?

Comment: it depends on what u want but usually you plot the real data for example with color 1 and the predicted data with color 2.